# ASP.Net Core: asp-action tag not working

Tags: asp.net-core

I have this simple anchor tag.

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Users" class="btn btn-default">Create</a>
```

The code structure is as follows.

[image]

The markup that is generated is as follows

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/Admin/Users">Create</a>
```

It is missing the action (create) but the rest of the tags seem to be working fine.

Routing setup is as follows

```
app.UseMvc(
    routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaRoute",
                template: "{area:exists}/controller=Admin/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Answer (score 8):

> The solution of this problem is to copy `~/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` to
>   `~/AreaName/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml`
>
> This is because the Tag helper is made available because of
>   `@addTagHelper` that is available in the `_ViewImports.cshtml page.`
>
> Once you have done this, your Tag helper intellisense works as well as
>   your Tag Helper code works!
>
> Hope this helps. Thanks

Reference: [[Resolved] Tag helper syntax is not working for the Areas view in ASP.NET Core - DotNetFunda.com](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/21879/tag-helper-syntax-is-not-working-for-the-areas-view-in-aspnet-core)

Comment: thank you , it was one heavy hour searching for a solution . AND here you are :)

Answer (score 3):

Order matters... put the area route above that of the default.

```
          routes.MapRoute(
                name: "adminDefault",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

           //catchall
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Area section in your project just copy _ViewImports.cshtml from your Views in the root folder to Areas>Admin>Views folder.
Be sure that this code be there in _Viewimports.cshtml

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```